# block specific word in layer 7

Tags: regex, firewall, blocking, mikrotik

I'm new here im configuring using winbox and I want to block a specific word in when search on Google.

in my filter rules i have my in chain:forward, protocol:6(tcp), Dst port:88,443
my layer 7 protocol is testblock, Action=drop
in my second filter rules chain:forward, protocol:6(tcp), Dst port:88,443

I add firewall L7 protocol name testblock, please help this is inside my Regexp  ^.*(:www.google.com|google.com).*\bhazel\b.*$

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I would place configuring a firewall off topic here - unless you're doing via an API and need help with that.

Comment: can you provide some exaple text, which you want to block and some you do not want to block? - looking at your regex, maybe `^.*(?:www\.)?google\.com.*\bhazel\b.*$` works for you?